# Youtube download'er in highest possible format (server side)

Tags: php, scripting, download, youtube, mp4

Welcome,

I'm looking for youtube api what allow me to download youtube video in highest possible format.

Few years ago this job was more simple because url had information about quality like "fmt=22" or "fmt=6" right now we are live in future and that information is embed in player.

Now it's more complex... google use cache servers and get_video doesn't work.

Look for example:
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XIz-MmKeoCs
(it's just example with HD don't comment music)

Right now i'm using old PHPtube class (2007 year).
phpclasses.org/browse/package/3966.html
It allow only to download file in lowest quality via flv.

My question is, anyone have class what allow download in highest possible ?

I give video ID -> XIz-MmKeoCs
It should check what quality is possible for download.
Right now i don't have any idea how get it...

And give download link. (of course i know about security used by IP, and want download file on my server using file_contents) but i got trouble only with getting that download link.

I will be great for any help...

Comment: When you say format what do you mean?  As far as I know YouTube videos are only available in two formats, standard, and (sometimes) HD.

Comment: Few days ago i wrote script what allow my users in LAN downloading mp3 from youtube.
First script download movie, then extract audio, convert to mp3 using lame and allow for download. (of course it's only for my LAN users)


Now i download in  flv 320p  but it have mono sound.

Than i notice that 480p if mp4 than have stereo sound if flv - mono 
And as you said HD in 720p  (mp4 - got great stereo sound)

So i need to check what format are available and download highest possible to get best audio quality.

Have you any idea ?
I most interested by mp4 version... but if not possible get low flv

Answer (score 2):

Use this post as a guideline: [youtube get_video not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4602956/youtube-get-video-not-working/5132711#5132711)

Using the $ytarr['fmt_url_map'] from that example, you can explode() it into the various available formats:

```
$fmt_array = array('5','34','35');    
$fmt_available = explode(',', $ytarr['fmt_stream_map']);
foreach ($fmt_array as $val) {
    foreach ($fmt_available as $fmtstr) {
        if (strpos($fmtstr,"$val|") !== false){
            $format = explode('|', $fmtstr);
            break 2;
        }
    }
}
echo $format['1'];
```

$fmt_array would hold all the formats you desire in order of priority. In this example, it would first print the direct link to format 5, and if 5 wasn't available it'd print 34, and so forth. You would obviously want to change that array to first list the highest formats.

Answer (score 0):

If you pull a video page, parse it and look for &fmt_url_map=  the stuff after here is a map of format id => download link.  You have to do a little parsing of it but have a look and it's not that complicated.

The problem is that if you are developing this on your machine, it will work, but if you want to put it live it will not work as the download urls have some sort of signature that only applies for the machine that pulled the video page, which in this case will not match with your local machine.