# how do i get the flv file path from a youtube URL

Tags: youtube, flv

i have an swf media player
which play flv videos 
but i want it to play youtube videos
so i must pass to the player flv file path

the senario is a website which i can upload videos or put a url
and i can put a youtube video URL

i am using asp.net
and i need a solution 
whenever i detect a user is entering youtube video
i must convert it to flv file path to be played in the player

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This post explains how to retrieve links of different qualities (FLV and more): [youtube get_video not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4602956/youtube-get-video-not-working/5132711#5132711)

However, if you're just going to play the videos, it would be easiest to use Youtube's chromeless player API: http://code.google.com/apis/youtube/flash_api_reference.html

Answer (score -1):

**You can use a current web service which is already implemented for your project**

Use www.keepvid.com to decode the url from YouTube. First go to YouTube and load a video then you copy the url in the address bar and it should show something like this:

> http://chi-v48.chi.youtube.com/get_video?video_id=TvedUxLtZKQ

One thing left to do is to add .flv to the end of the url so it ends up like this:

> http://chi-v48.chi.youtube.com/get_video?video_id=TvedUxLtZKQ.flv

Comment: @Suadantha stackoveflow is not place of advertising