# Displaying Youtube videos in native player

Tags: mobile, smartface.io

How can display Youtube videos in Smartface video player, not in a webview?

How do I obtain the necessary video stream information from Youtube?

Answer (score 0):

You can check this link to get .flv path [how do i get the flv file path from a youtube URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4690985/how-do-i-get-the-flv-file-path-from-a-youtube-url)

But in general, native players doesn't support .flv extension.

The best way to show a youtube video in your app is to use WebView component.