# cordova-youtube-video-player not working iOS XCDYouTubeKit

Tags: ios, cordova

Seems like https://www.youtube.com/get_video_info not working anymore, therefore the XCDYouTubeKit cannot get video info anymore and the plugin doesnt seem to be working in iOS. This started a few days ago as far as I know... anyone knows how to fix/workaround?

Getting this response:

> [XCDYouTubeKit] Failed to decode response from [https://www.youtube.com/get_video_info?el=embedded&hl=en-US&ps=default&video_id=[VIDEOID]](https://www.youtube.com/get_video_info?el=embedded&hl=en-US&ps=default&video_id=%5BVIDEOID%5D) (response.textEncodingName = utf-8, data.length = 0)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4602956/youtube-get-video-not-working

Comment: I'm getting this as well.

Answer (score 1):

A hotfix for now is to add this line to your PodFile:

```
pod 'XCDYouTubeKit', git: 'https://github.com/jatin19121990/XCDYouTubeKit', branch: 'hotfix/Can-Not-Play-video-any-more---XCDYouTubeVideoErrorDomain-Code=-3-#525', submodules: true
```

replacing the old :

```
pod 'XCDYouTubeKit'
```

and then run at platforms/ios folder:

```
pod install
```

As stated here:

https://github.com/0xced/XCDYouTubeKit/issues/525